# How can i find minimal string in c++

Tags: c++, string

For example, if i input age, boy, age (this is situation first if, third () ), the program does otput nothing, like " " . I do not understand where is my mistake.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string a, b, c;
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    if ((a < b && a < c) || (a == b && a < c) || (a == c && a < b)) {
        cout << a;
    }
    if ((b < a && b < c) || (a == b && b < c) || (c == b && b < a)) {
        cout << b;
    }
    if ((c < b && c < a) || (c == b && c < a) || (c == a && c < b)) {
        cout << c;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The output (supposing that `string` is provided by your `<iostream>`) is `ageage`. Test it here: https://ideone.com/uSbCks

Comment: Make a [mcve] by removing the input from `cin` and setting `a`, `b` and `c` in a fixed manner.

Comment: @dspr: the output is `ageage` because both the first and the third if get executed. Anyway, there's a lot of space for improving that code.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do as

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string a, b, c;
    std::cin >> a >> b >> c;
    std::cout << std::min({a, b, c}) << '\n'; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @starboy_jb you should always check your answers before posting, otherwise you will be subject to downvotes. But the good news is that you can edit your own answer yourself, or you can even delete it. From a reputation point of view, it is better to delete its own answer than leaving a wrong answer.